# Getting complete product information using Amazon Product API

Tags: amazon-product-api, paapi, amazon-paapi

I've just started with the Amazon Product Advertising API and I have to say the documentation is throwing me against walls. I'm using the PHP library to get basic item information.

The question I have, I can get results on a search or I can get individual items by the ASIN. However for those items they often have unique attributes.

For example; a book might have a Genre, and a SSD drive would have a value for the number of Gigabytes/Terabytes.

I have no idea what methods or corners of the API i need to reference to even surface that data. I'm beginning to think it does not.

I am using [getItems](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/get-items.html) and digging into [ItemInfo](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/item-info.html) and other resources as part of the response.

Can anyone provide an example of a request that gets such attributes of a product (any language), or can call out the specific methods that I should be looking at?

To clarify; taking this screenshot of an Amazon listing you will see on right side...

[image: Screenshot of an product on Amazon]

1. Variations (Variations on drive with prices)
2. Product Overview ('Digital Storage Capacity: 2TB' etc.)
3. "About this item"

I am unable to return Variations (1) and the "About this item" (3) text.

What I am missing is the data in the "Product Overview" (2). Any pointers/directions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself familiarized with the [Resources](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/resources.html). Resources have all the information Amazon has to share.

To answer to your question:

1. Variations can be fetched using different API operation - [GetVariations](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/get-variations.html).
2. Product overview is present as part of Resources in the ItemInfo - [Features](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/item-info.html#features).

Other details like if it is technical info, the details would be present under ItemInfo - [TechnicalInfo](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/item-info.html#technicalinfo)

Note: To get all the Resources in response, you need to add it Resources you need in the request body. Check their examples out.

To simplify, they also have the option of playing around with API using a web page called Scratchpad. Once you have search entered in the UI and run it, it automatically gives an entire code snippet of how to fetch using code.